# concat of parts of list

Tags: elisp, concatenation

What am I missing?

As they say: In every program is a bug.

```
(defun test-test ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((lll (list "a" "b")))
        (message (concat "<" (car lll) ":" (cdar lll) ">"))
))
```

Error:

```
concat: Wrong type argument: listp, "a"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misspelled your `cadr` :).

```
(defun test-test ()
  (let ((lll (list "a" "b")))
    (message (concat "<" (car lll) ":" (cadr lll) ">"))))
```

Also, you don't need interactive, if you don't plan to call it with <kbd>M-x</kbd>

Comment: iteractive means fastest testing for me

Comment: fastest testing is in scratch with C-j

Answer (score 0):

Enable "Options => Enter Debugger on Error" in the menu, and you'll get a backtrace that should clarify the problem.